# Setting variable outside a block from inside a block?

Tags: ruby

I have following code:

```
def test_callback_interface
  with_temp_stdio do |stdin, stdout|
    stdin.write("hello\n")
    stdin.close
    stdout.flush
    line = nil

    replace_stdio(stdin.path, stdout.path) {
      Readline.handler_install("> ", true) { |l| line = l }
      6.times { Readline.read_char }
      Readline.handler_remove
    }

    assert_equal("hello", line)     <------ FAIL here
    assert_equal(true, line.tainted?)
    stdout.rewind
    assert_equal("> ", stdout.read(2))
    assert_equal(1, Readline::HISTORY.length)
    assert_equal("hello", Readline::HISTORY[0])
  end

  assert_equal(true, false)
end
```

it fails on the line `assert_equal("hello", line)` saying that the `line` is `nil`. However, I'm sure that the callback is called (I verified it by putting `raise` in there). So I must be missing something fundamental about scopes here. Could someone please enlighten me how to get the value of `l` to the `line` variable?

Thanks

EDIT:

How do I call the callback inside handler_install/read_char?

```
static VALUE readline_callback_ensure(VALUE val) {
    free(readline_callback_line);
    readline_callback_line = NULL;
    return Qnil;
}
static VALUE readline_callback_call(VALUE line) {
    VALUE proc = rb_attr_get(mReadline, read_char_cb_proc);
    rb_funcall(proc, id_call, 1, line);
    return Qnil;
}
static void readline_callback_callback(char * line) {
    if (readline_callback_add_history && line) {
        add_history(line);
    }
    readline_callback_line = line;
    rb_ensure(
        readline_callback_call, line ? rb_str_new_cstr(line) : Qnil,
        readline_callback_ensure, Qnil
    );
}
static VALUE readline_callback_handler_install(int argc, VALUE * argv, VALUE self) {
    VALUE tmp, add_hist, block;
    char * prompt = NULL;

    rb_need_block();

    if (rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "02&", &tmp, &add_hist, &block) > 0) {
        prompt = RSTRING_PTR(tmp);
    }

    if (RTEST(add_hist)) {
        readline_callback_add_history = true;
    } else {
        readline_callback_add_history = false;
    }

    rb_ivar_set(mReadline, read_char_cb_proc, block);

    rl_callback_handler_install(prompt, readline_callback_callback);

    return Qnil;
}

static VALUE readline_callback_read_char(VALUE self) {
    VALUE proc = rb_attr_get(mReadline, read_char_cb_proc);
    if (NIL_P(proc)) {
        rb_raise(rb_eRuntimeError, "No handler installed.");
    }
    rl_callback_read_char();
    return Qnil;
}
```

So basically `read_char` calls `rl_callback_read_char` (gnu readline function), which on detecting complete line invokes my installed handler `readline_callback_callback` which invoked stored block supplied by user.

Comment: Can you show us, how do you call the callback inside `handler_install`?

Comment: I don't believe it's a scope issue. Try changing the block `{ |l| line = l }` to  `{ |l| puts "l = #{l}"; line = l }`.

Comment: @fangxing I modified my question to provide additional details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, not an scope issue. GNU Readline calls my code once more with NULL on EOF, complete forgot about that.